# Excel query with regards to IF statements

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have the following formula in an excel sheet that generally works perfectly:

```
=IF(F5>=30.01,(39+(C5*0.08)),IF(AND(F5>=20.01,F5<=30),(39+(C5*0.07)),IF(AND(F5>=10.01,F5<=20),(39+(C5*0.06)),IF(AND(F5>=5.01,F5<=10),(39+(C5*0.05)),IF(AND(F5>=2.01,F5<=5),(39+(C5*0.04)),IF(AND(F5>=1.01,F5<=2),(39+(C5*0.03)),IF(AND(F5>=0.25,F5<=1),(39+(C5*0.02)),IF(AND(F5>=0,F5<=0.245),(0.03*C5*F5)))))))))
```

I was just wondering if anyone could tell me how to edit this so that if the result of the formula is less than '43', that the number inputted into the cell should be 43?

I have been trying to edit this accordingly for a while and I'm not sure what I need to do to make that happen.

The rest of the formula works exactly as I need it to, I just need the sheet not to produce a result that is less than 43.

Thank you so much for all your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the AND statements as the very nature of the nested ifs picks them off scaling down, Here is your current formula amended:

```
=IF(F5>=30.01,(39+(C5*0.08)),IF(F5>=20.01,(39+(C5*0.07)),IF(F5>=10.01,(39+(C5*0.06)),IF(F5>=5.01,(39+(C5*0.05)),IF(F5>=2.01,(39+(C5*0.04)),IF(F5>=1.01,(39+(C5*0.03)),IF(F5>=0.25,(39+(C5*0.02)),IF(F5>=0,(0.03*C5*F5)))))))))
```

You could then wrap it in a MAX formula to get either the result or 43, whichever is larger like so:

```
=MAX(IF(F5>=30.01,(39+(C5*0.08)),IF(F5>=20.01,(39+(C5*0.07)),IF(F5>=10.01,(39+(C5*0.06)),IF(F5>=5.01,(39+(C5*0.05)),IF(F5>=2.01,(39+(C5*0.04)),IF(F5>=1.01,(39+(C5*0.03)),IF(F5>=0.25,(39+(C5*0.02)),IF(F5>=0,(0.03*C5*F5))))))))),43)
```

Answer (score 0):

the formula can also be adjusted further in order to group common factors as follows:

```
=MAX(SUM(IF(F5<=0,0,39),
IF(F5>30,(C5*0.08),
IF(F5>20,(C5*0.07),
IF(F5>10,(C5*0.06),
IF(F5>5,(C5*0.05),
IF(F5>2,(C5*0.04),
IF(F5>1,(C5*0.03),
IF(F5>=0.25,(C5*0.02),
IF(F5>=0,(0.03*C5*F5),0))))))))),43)
```

Long formulas are always difficult to read, may I suggest to use the *Alt+Enter* keys combined to start a new line in the same cell thus breaking your formula in several lines within the same cell.

Certainly, The revised formula should be like this:

```
=IF(F5=0,0,
MAX(SUM(IF(F5<=0,0,39),
IF(F5>30,(C5*0.08),
IF(F5>20,(C5*0.07),
IF(F5>10,(C5*0.06),
IF(F5>5,(C5*0.05),
IF(F5>2,(C5*0.04),
IF(F5>1,(C5*0.03),
IF(F5>=0.25,(C5*0.02),
IF(F5>=0,(0.03*C5*F5),0))))))))),43))
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Why the first line, out of curiosity? What function does it have? 

I do like the idea of if F5 is <=0 to have the cell just be blank, but why the 39? (At least I think that's what it means).

Comment: It corresponds to the +39 that is repeated within every IF in your original formula, so if F5 is not zero then to add 39 once and not every other time

Comment: Can I edit your formula such that if F5 were 0, to display 0?

Comment: Sorry Hassan, new to this and don't know how to format in comments, very knew to comments as well.. I'll post the revised formula in the answer. Apologies for the trouble…